# Dynamic map creation in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a map passed as variable

```
dummy = {
  1 = {
    instances = {
      "ip1" = {
        a = "earth"
        b = "hi"
        c = 1
      }
      "ip2" = {
        a = "world"
        b = "hello"
        c = 2
      }
      "ip3" = {
        a = "planet"
        b = "hey"
        c = 3
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want construct a map as follows

```
value = {
  "ip1" = {
    b = "hi"
    c = 1
  }
  "ip2" = {
    b = "hello"
    c = 2
  }
  "ip3" = {
    b = "hey"
    c = 3
  }
}
```

I tried using for loops but nothing seems to work out
The following is what I have tried since

```
_meta = {
  for instance in var.dummy.1.instances:
    (instance.key) = {
      b = instance.value.b
      c = instance.value.c
    }
}
```

But it says I cant access the key with for iteration variable

Comment: `(instance.key)` should be `instance.key`. What error occurs after that fix?

Comment: @MattSchuchard
Error: Invalid 'for' expression

  on test.tf line 12, in resource "consul_keys" "app":
  10:
  11:
  12:             instance.key = {
  13:
  14:
  15:
  16:

Key expression is required when building an object.


Error: Invalid 'for' expression

  on test.tf line 12, in resource "consul_keys" "app":
  10:
  11:
  12:             instance.key = {

Extra characters after the end of the 'for' expression.

Comment: Since this is a nested map, you also need to enclose the outer expression in `{}` as well, so `{ instance.key = ... }}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
_meta = {
  for key, instance in var.dummy.1.instances:
    key => {
      b = instance.b
      c = instance.c
    }
}
```

A for expression is a bit different from a for_each. You don't get **key** or **value** variables in a for expression and you can explicitly pull whole entries from the map as I've shown above using **key, value in map** as the expression form.

You also need to use a fat arrow `=>` operator between the key and value of the generated map entries.